# How can I use a newly written value in a required file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to change a value within a config and then use that new value later?

```
// CONFIG.JSON
// BEFORE CHANGE
{
    "value": "baz"
}
// AFTER CHANGE
{
    "value": "foobar"
}

// MAIN JS ILE
const config = require('config.json')

function changeValue() {
    config['value'] = "foobar"
    var config_string = JSON.stringify(config, null, 4)
    fs.writeFile(config_dir, config_string, (err) => {
        if (err) {console.log("error", err)}
    })
}

function useValue() {
    console.log(config['value'])
    // output will be "baz"
    // fs.writeFile does not change the file data until the end of the whole script
    // which is why I need help, how can I change a value and use it if ^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) instead which is synchronous and blocking, this means that your other code won't run until the file has finished being written.

```js
// CONFIG.JSON
// BEFORE CHANGE
{
    "value": "baz"
}
// AFTER CHANGE
{
    "value": "foobar"
}

// MAIN JS ILE
const config = require('config.json')

function changeValue() {
    config['value'] = "foobar"
    var config_string = JSON.stringify(config, null, 4)
    fs.writeFileSync(config_dir, config_string)
    // Will wait until the file is fully written, before moving on
}

function useValue() {
    console.log(config['value'])
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder: when writing Javascript, one should generally prefer "asynchronous" over "synchronous" code whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Easy - just assign a callback.

For example:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefile-method/
>
> ```
> const fs = require('fs');
>   
> let data = "This is a file containing a collection of books.";
>   
> fs.writeFile("books.txt", data, (err) => {
>   if (err)
>     console.log(err);
>   else {
>     console.log("File written successfully\n");
>     console.log("The written has the following contents:");
>     console.log(fs.readFileSync("books.txt", "utf8"));
>   }
> });
> ```

In your case, perhaps something like:

```
function changeValue() {
    config['value'] = "foobar"
    var config_string = JSON.stringify(config, null, 4)
    fs.writeFile(config_dir, config_string, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
          // UseValue stuff...
        } else {
          console.log("error", err)}
        }
    })
}
```

Here's another example:

[fs.writeFile() doesn't return callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545043/fs-writefile-doesnt-return-callback)